# Nativescript Angular HTTP - Provider not Found

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm trying to get HTTP in a nativescript app up and running.

My module bootstrapping looks like this:

```
// this import should be first in order to load some required settings (like globals and reflect-metadata)
import { platformNativeScriptDynamic, NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/platform";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import {MainPage, ListTest, ItemComponent} from "./main-page";
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {NativeScriptHttpModule} from 'nativescript-angular/http';



@NgModule({
    declarations: [MainPage, ListTest,ItemComponent],
    bootstrap: [MainPage],
    imports: [NativeScriptModule,NativeScriptHttpModule]
})
class AppComponentModule { }

platformNativeScriptDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppComponentModule, NativeScriptHttpModule);
```

When I start the app, I get the following runtime exception:

I get the following error `n ./MainPage class MainPage_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: No provider for NSHttp!`

Any ideas?

Comment: what if you add HttpModule like `imports:[...,HttpModule]`?

Comment: problem is that this quite old now as from angular 2.0 and not RC versions they changed it best would be either check it inside tutorial for NS+ng2 or sample projects where its working

Comment: I believe the problem is that you’re passing `NativeScriptHttpModule` into `bootstrapModule()`. Remove that; `NativeScriptHttpModule` only needs to appear as an import in your app’s main `@NgModule`.